# Finding related nodes by label that are not returned in paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have three start nodes returning paths `p1,p2,p3` that all end at a common node `com`. All the nodes in the three paths have the label `type`. Zero or more of the nodes in each path have a second label type `file`. I want to find all of the `file` nodes that are parents of the node `com` that are not in paths `p1,p2,p3`.

```
MATCH p1=(s1:type{id:882591})-[:sub*0..35]->(com:type{id:882680})
MATCH p2=(s2:type{id:541990})-[:sub*0..35]->(com) 
MATCH p3=(s3:type{id:542007})-[:sub*0..35]->(com)  
WITH com, collect(p1) as pa, collect(p2) as pb, collect(p3) as pc
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:file)-[:sub*0..35]->(com)
WHERE NOT f IN pa AND NOT f IN pb AND NOT f IN pc
RETURN DISTINCT f limit 100
```

This is the closest I've gotten but it still returns all `file` nodes that are parents of `com` - even those in the paths. The first nodes and last node `com` of each path will never have the label `file` if it's faster to remove them. Thanks for you help!

Comment: As a possible slight improvement: a variable length path should use a lower bound of `1` (the default) instead of `0` if it is impossible for the start and end nodes to be the same node. This happens to apply to all four variable length paths in your specific example (but may not always be true, depending on your actual use case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect on paths p1,p2, and p3 will be a list of paths and not the nodes.

Try `nodes(p1) as pa` and so on to collect nodes.

**EDIT:**

> As suggested by @InverseFalcon above query have cardinality issue.

You can create a collection of these nodes ids and unwind it to have a single match to find these paths.

```
WITH [882591,541990,542007] as typeIds
UNWIND typeIds as typeId
MATCH p=(s1:type{id:typeId})-[:sub*0..35]->(com:type{id:882680})
WITH com, nodes(p) as ps
OPTIONAL MATCH (f:file)-[:sub*0..35]->(com)
WHERE NOT f IN ps
RETURN DISTINCT f 
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: @Damon Also important, collect the nodes after each path match (and add to the shared collection) rather than collecting at the end. You've got a multiplicative cardinality issue happening (PROFILE your query to see the db hits and rows blow up).

Comment: @InverseFalcon What if matching one path instead of 3 and match id of starting node in where clause with IN. like id in the list of these 3 ids?